# Two interrogatives in one clause

Tags: usage

If there are two interrogatives in one clause, is it normal that one interrogative is placed at the front and the other at the end? For example, 'What amount of money did you steal where?' How about 'What amount of money and where did you steal?'

Comment: Your proposed alternative is **not** idiomatic.

Comment: There is no rule on how to handle two questions in one. You can make things clearer: 'What amount of money did you steal, **and where did you steal it**?'

Comment: Paul, so, only 'What amount of money did you steal where' is idiomatic? Any other ways to communicate the same message?

Comment: Your suggested alternant is ungrammatical because "steal" here requires an object like "it". Your first example is OK, though.

Comment: "What amount of money did you steal and where did you steal it from?" is one way, or simply "What amount of money did you steal and from where?'

Comment: How about 'What amount of money and where did you steal'? It is not grammatical, either, right?